# Conditional probability - Basketball player

Tags: probability

A basketball player has a chance of 80% on his free throw shoots and 30% on his three-point shoots. If he makes free throw shoots N times and then makes three-point shoots as many times as the successful shoots he made in his free throw shoots, find

a)the probability mass function of the successful three-point shoots

b)If N=3 , what the probability he scores 1 three-point shoot

Any help?

I can see this is a conditional probability and the two variables are binomial , X= the number of the free throw shoots ~ Bin(N,0.8) and let m be the successful free throw shoots and Y=the number of the three-point shoots ~ Bin(m,0.3).
I don't know how two get the conditional probability when the two variables are binomial.

Thank you!

Comment: Any thoughts, progress and general effort made on your side towards answering this question on your own?

Comment: I can see this is a conditional probability and the two variables are binomial , X= the number of the free throw shoots ~ Bin(N,0.8) and let m be the successful shoots and Y=the number of the three-point shoots ~ Bin(m,0.3)

Comment: What I meant to suggest is that you add all of that to your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ denote the number of successful $2$-point shots.

Let $Y$ denote the number of successful $3$-point shots.

---

$P(Y=m)=$

$\sum\limits_{k=m}^{N}P(Y=m|X=k)=$

$\sum\limits_{k=m}^{N}\binom{N}{k}\cdot(0.8)^k\cdot(1-0.8)^{N-k}\cdot\binom{k}{m}\cdot(0.3)^m\cdot(1-0.3)^{k-m}$

---

Using this with $N=3$ and $m=1$ gives a probability of $0.415872$.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! MUCH APPRECIATED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Antouanet: You're welcome, feel free to accept the answer by clicking on the V next to it :)

Comment: To be honest i was trying to find a way to rate you (if there is something like this- it is my first time on the site)!! thank you!!! done !